# Can't add the fragment to activity programmatically

Tags: android, android-fragments

Yes. I know that there are a lot of the questions like mine, BUT I watched them all (I guess)

I think that I am doing everything right, but it still does not work
I have a frameLayout. I tried to use add() instead of replace() and that does not work.

I try to add a fragment in OnLoadFinished() - method.

My code:

```
Bundle fragBundle = new Bundle();
fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ContactInfoFragment contactInfoFragment = (ContactInfoFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("contactInfo");
if (contactInfoFragment == null){
    switch(type) {
        case "44": {
                //passing some data to bundle
                break;
            }
            case "223":{
                //passing some data to bundle
                break;
            }
        }
        contactInfoFragment = new ContactInfoFragment();
        contactInfoFragment.setArguments(fragBundle);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.contact_layout, contactInfoFragment, "contactInfo");
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
    }
```

Please, help me

My Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:background="#ffffff"
tools:context="com.example.tenderplan.activities.ElementActivity">

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:background="#ffffff"
tools:context="com.example.tenderplan.activities.ElementActivity"
android:id="@+id/element_layout"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/contact_layout">
    </FrameLayout>

    <fragment
        android:name="com.example.tenderplan.fragments.DocumentsFragment"
        android:id="@+id/documents_fragment"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/documents_fragment"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_info_fragment"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/attachmentslayout2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/documents_fragment">
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id = "@+id/comments_layout">
    </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Actually, I need the contact_layout to be replaced.

Comment: What version of Android are you supporting? Are you calling this code from a `Fragment` or `Activity`? And can you please post your `Layout`.

Comment: min api 14, I am calling this from Activity. w8 a minute, ill add layout

Comment: Whether `onLoadFinish()` method is calling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not commit fragment transactions in onLoadFinish, you can read:

> Called when a previously created loader has finished its load. Note that normally an application is not allowed to commit fragment transactions while in this call, since it can happen after an activity's state is saved. See FragmentManager.openTransaction() for further discussion on this.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html#onLoadFinished%28android.content.Loader%3CD%3E,%20D%29

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#beginTransaction()

so what you should do is to use [commitAllowingStateLoss()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commitAllowingStateLoss()) instead of commit().